# mkfifo() error ---> "Error creating the named pipe.: File exists"

Tags: c, systems-programming, mkfifo

The mkfifo function takes 2 arguments, path and mode.  But I don't know what is the format of the path that it uses.  I am writing a small program to create a named pipe and as path in the `mkfifo`.   Using `/home/username/Documents` for example, but it always returns -1 with the message `Error creating the named pipe.: File exists`.

I have checked this dir a lot of times and there is no pipe inside it. So I am wondering what is the problem.  The mode I use in mkfifo is either 0666 or 0777.

Comment: can you add the exact function call ?

Comment: Errr, did you forget to give the named pipe a name? The path is directory + `/` + file name, so `/home/username/Documents/mypipe`.

Comment: char *myfifo="/home/username/Documents";
mkfifo(myfifo,0777);

Comment: Thanks all for the answers...Michal right...I didnt give name..I will check this now...Thanks again!

Comment: It compiles and works fine now!Thanks a lot!:)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You gave [`mkfifo()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/mkfifo.html) the name of an *existing* directory, thus the error. You must give it the name of a non-existing file, e.g.

```
mkfifo("/home/username/Documents/myfifo", 0600);
```

Comment: Thank you!Just understood that.:)

Answer (score 2):

The 'path' argument to `mkfifo()` has to specify a full path, the directory and the filename that is.

Thus, it would be:

```
char *myfifo="/home/username/Documents/mypipe";

mkfifo(myfifo, 0777);
```

As a side note, you should avoid using octal permission bits and use named constants instead (from `sys/stat.h`), so:

```
mkfifo(myfifo, S_IRWXU | S_IRWXG | S_IRWXO);
```

Comment: What's wrong with octal permissions?  They are extremely standard and universal.

Comment: And octal permissions are a whole heap more succinct, too!  However, in theory, you're supposed to use the S_Iwxyz names.  In practice, you'll be fine almost everywhere using octal instead.

Comment: @wallyk: The problem with octal permissions is that they are *not* standard. POSIX doesn't require compliant implementations to use any specific values. And using symbolic constants has another benefit too -- you can use `#ifdef` to check whether a particular mode is supported at all.